# Object Reference not set to an instance of object in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm creating new product belonging to the category model.When i execute my Create method, the error invoke that

> "Object Reference not set to instance of object" on "model" object

My Controller class:

```
public ActionResult CreateProduct()   
{
    SetCateProductViewBag();
    return View(new CateProdViewModel());
}

[HttpPost]       
public ActionResult CreateProduct(CateProdViewModel model)
{

    var ValidImageTypes = new String[]
    {
        "image/gif",
        "image/jpeg",
        "image/jpg",
        "image/pjpeg",
        "image/png"
    };
    if (model.ImageUpload == null || model.ImageUpload.ContentLength == 0)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("ImageUpload", "This Field is required.");
    }
    else if (!ValidImageTypes.Contains(model.ImageUpload.ContentType))
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("ImageUload", "Please choose either a GIF,jpg or png type of file.");
    }
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        var prod = new Product
        {
            //   CategoryName =model.category.CategoryName,
            //CategoryDescription=model.category.CategoryDescription,

            //CategoryId=model.CategoryId,
            ProductName = model.ProductName,
            ProductDescription = model.ProductDescription,
            Model = model.Model,
            ProductPrice = model.ProductPrice,
            AvailableForSale = model.AvailableForSale,
            Shippable = model.Shippable,
            AvailableStock = model.AvailableStock,
            ProductPicture = model.ProductPicture

        };
        SetCateProductViewBag(prod.CategoryId);
        if (model.ImageUpload != null && model.ImageUpload.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            var UploadDir = "~/Uploads";
            var ImagePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(UploadDir), model.ImageUpload.FileName);
            var ImageUrl = Path.Combine(UploadDir, model.ImageUpload.FileName);
            model.ImageUpload.SaveAs(ImagePath);
            prod.ProductPicture = ImageUrl;
        }
        productContext.product.Add(prod);
        productContext.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("CategoryIndex");
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

CateProdViewModel class:

```
public class CateProdViewModel
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string CategoryDescription { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public int AvailableStock { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public bool AvailableForSale { get; set; }
    public bool Shippable { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.ImageUrl)]
    public string ProductPicture { get; set; }
    public int SelectedValue { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public HttpPostedFileBase ImageUpload { get; set; }
    public virtual Category category { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Product Categories")]
    public virtual ICollection<Category> categories { get; set; }
}
```

Entity classes for Category and Product:

```
public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public string ProductDescription { get; set; }
    public int AvailableStock { get; set; }
    public decimal ProductPrice { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public bool AvailableForSale { get; set; }
    public bool Shippable { get; set; }
    public string ProductPicture { get; set; }
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category category { get; set; }

}

 public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public string CategoryDescription { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> product { get; set; }

}
```

My View:

```
@model SmartShoppingCart.Models.CateProdViewModel

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "CreateProduct";
}

<h2>Create Product</h2>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.CategoryId,"Category")
        @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId",ViewBag.categories as SelectList, string.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.CategoryId)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.CategoryId)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.ProductName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.ProductName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.ProductName)
    </div>
     <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.ProductDescription)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.ProductDescription)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.ProductDescription)
    </div>
     <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Model)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Model)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Model)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.ProductPrice)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.ProductPrice)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.ProductPrice)
    </div>
     <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.AvailableForSale)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.AvailableForSale)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.AvailableForSale)
    </div>
     <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.Shippable)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.Shippable)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Shippable)
    </div>
     <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.AvailableStock)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m=>m.AvailableStock)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.AvailableStock)
    </div>
    <div>
        @Html.LabelFor(m=>m.ImageUpload)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ImageUpload, new {type="file" })
    </div>
    <div>
         <button type="submit" value="Add" ></button>
    </div>
</form>

private void SetCateProductViewBag(int? CateId = null)
{
    if (CateId == null)
    {
        ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(productContext.category, "CategoryId", "CategoryName");
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.Categories = new SelectList(productContext.category.ToArray(),"CategoryId","CategoryName",CateId);
    }
}
```

Comment: What line are you getting the error. That's usually how you can tell

Comment: I am getting the error at this line:if (model.ImageUpload == null || model.ImageUpload.ContentLength == 0)

Comment: model must be null, or ContentLength is not an int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error occurs because your model is null on post back. The model is null because it contains a property named `Model` and the parameter name of the action method is also named `model` which is confusing the poor `DefaultModelBinder`. Either change the name of the property to something else or change the parameter name in your post action method to something else.

Comment: Its working fine now. but now m getting the null value for product picture,category. while CategoryId and ProductId is taking 0 values. and the error occurred "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint \"FK_Product_Category1\". The conflict occurred in database \"ShoppingCart\", table \"dbo.Category\", column 'CategoryId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

Comment: You got other errors in the view - I'll check and update answer

Comment: As for CategoryID, use `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CategoryId, ViewBag.categories as SelectList)` and delete `@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.CategoryId)`. As for ProductId and ProductPicture , you don't seem to be rendering any type of `input` or `select` for these properties

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you change the first action to:

```
public ActionResult CreateProduct(CateProdViewModel model)   
{
    SetCateProductViewBag();
    return View(model);
}
```

And your `DefaultModelBinder` will instantiate the model so it's never null.

Other than that, I need to know what you mean by saying `When i execute my Create method`. Since you don't have a `Create` method there. You have `CreateProduct` and you got 2 of them. Is this a `POST` or `GET` request?

Comment: Yes i was talking about the CreateProduct action method.By setting the same parameters in get an post request there invoke the error. Its not getting executed.